# Apache Flume + Hdfs Sink

Tags: apache, flume

Can we add a delimiter for HDFS Sink ?
When is file is written , how can we add a record seperator ?

Following are the configuration :-

```
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.type = hdfs
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.channel = memory
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.path=tmp/kafka/%{topic}/%y-%m-%d
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.rollSize=268435456
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.rollCount=0
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp=true
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.inUseSuffix=.tmp
 tier1.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.batchSize=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would lean towards using a Flume EventSerializer whose configuration would be similar than this one:

```
tier1.sinks.hdfssink.serializer = <your serialization class>
tier1.sinks.hdfssink.serializer.delimiter = < your delimiter>
```

You might reference the following github site for details and code snippets.

https://github.com/relistan/flume-serializers

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank you for your response